# Getting Tkinter to pause one second

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, delay

I'm trying to build a simple photobooth type application with tkinter.  I think I have what I want, except that tkinter isn't actually pausing (countdown to photo taken) when it should.

Here's a barebones example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Photobooth:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title('Photo Booth')
        self.seconds = 3
        self.secs = 3
        self.num_photos = 0

        self.display = tk.Label(master, height=20, width=60, textvariable="")
        self.display.config(text='Photobooth!')
        self.display.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1)

        self.three_photo_button = tk.Button(master,
                                            bg='Blue',
                                            activebackground='Dark Blue',
                                            text='Take 3 Photos',
                                            width=60,
                                            height=8,
                                            command=lambda: self.take_photos(3))
        self.three_photo_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def tick(self):
        # Need a dummy function to pause with.
        pass

    def take_photos(self, num_photos):
        self.secs = self.seconds
        # Cycle through each photo
        for n in range(num_photos):
            # Cycle through countdown timer
            for s in range(self.seconds):
                # Display seconds left
                self.display.config(text='{}'.format(self.secs))

                if self.secs == 0:
                    # "Take photo" by displaying text
                    self.display.config(text='Took {} of {} photos!'.format(n, num_photos))
                    # Wait a fraction of a second, then continue.
                    self.master.after(100, self.tick)
                    # Except if we are at our photo limit, then show: 'Done'.
                    if n == (num_photos - 1):
                        self.display.config(text='Done!')
                        self.master.after(100, self.tick)
                else:
                    # Decrease timer
                    self.secs -= 1
                    # Wait one second
                    self.master.after(1000, self.tick)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_timer = Photobooth(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

When I run the application, it seems to work, but everything runs through too quick (no pausing). I'm new to tkinter, but the `after()` function should make the application loop pause, which it doesn't seem to do.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.wait_variable-method and https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2000-June/052951.html

Answer (score 1):

This should give you some idea of how you can think:

```
def take_photos(self,num_photos):
    for i in range(num_photos):
        delay = (i+1) * 1000
        self.master.after(delay, self.take_one_photo, i+1, num_photos)

def take_one_photo(self,n,m):
    # "Take photo" by displaying text
    self.display.config(text='Took {} of {} photos!'.format(n, m))
```